# How I justify a text file in xcode?

Tags: ios7, justify

I have a txt file that is displayed in my application. I'm on my storyboard and select all the text. I click on the option for justifying and storyboar the standard text is justified but when I run the application it all this against the left. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;